# Can you use jQuery in an ePub

Tags: jquery, epub

I am looking at making an ePub magazine, but instead of making the user download a file each month, I would like to use XML and jQuery to load the correct data in the ePub document.

If this is possible that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you need a [Javascript enabled ePub reader](http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-epub-readers) for this to work. So the definite answer is: It depends.

Also, you should check, if your target group's epub reader, if it understands JS, can load data via HTTP.

Comment: The reason I ask, is I would like to make an ePub for the iPad Reader

Comment: Seems to work: http://blog.threepress.org/2010/06/24/javascript-and-interactivity-in-ibooks/ . I'd suggest to just try it. (You have an iPad, right?)

Answer (score 0):

At least, iBooks can handle jQuery (also, jQuery UI!) correctly.
You can get sample ePub file [here](http://www.sunbi.co.jp/category/epub/index.htm#jquery)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.  I also tried [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) as I don't need all the [Internet Explorer](http://explosion-pills.com/articles/33-Just-for-Fun/Truth/Why-IE-Sucks-for-Developers,-Users,-and-Why-it-Still-Won%27t-Die) gotchas and workarounds.